# Handling Out-of-Range Indices

Tags: c++, oop, exception

For a container class, what should the expected behavior be when the user of the class tries to set a value that's outside the class's size?

The method in question is a "replace" method (like `operator[]`), rather than an "add" method (like `operator+=`).

I could throw an `out_of_range` exception or I could just resize the container to accommodate the addition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An out of range exception is more appropriate here because "replace" semantics normally means that the caller is presuming/asserting there is data at the specified index, which there is not.

Comment: +1: I know we are talking about C++ here, but *explicit is better than implicit* still applies.

Answer (score 3):

For `std::vector::operator[]`, a domain error causes undefined behavior. For `std::map::operator[]`, a domain error creates a new entry. I guess the design questions are:

- How expensive is it to extend the container? That is, can you create just one item (like `map::operator[]`), or do you have to create all of the intervening items (like `vector::operator[]`)
- How expensive is the range check, compared to the access function? In `map`, the range check is free once you've run the access function. In `vector` the range check approximately doubles the cost off the access.

Since you are designing the container, feel free to impose whichever pattern suits you and your customers. Just be sure to document the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I prefer throwing out-of-range exception. If the users really want to expand the storage, offer them a method to do so. This will eliminate many unintentional expansions, which could lead to more serious bugs. This is just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

One point not yet mentioned is that it may sometimes be useful to provide for a special one-over case to extend the class size.  The idea is that a class may have an invariant that items[0] to item[length-1] have all been validly assigned.  If one attempts to write to item[K], with K>=length+1, it may be necessary to create new items [length..K-1] with unknown values, breaking the class invariant.  On the other hand, if one writes to item[length], one could increment length by one and maintain the class invariant.